# Cannot login to my ubuntu after some unity hacking

Tags: unity, login, launcher, bazaar, hacking

I installed unity 7 using

```
bzr lp:unity trunk
```

and I wanted to try a small hack to get started what I did is that I just modified the sentence that appears in the search box when you open the launcher and I did `make` and then `sudo make install` to install the new unity binary in `~/staging/bin` then I run `unity --replace &` to test if the change was applied but since then I am unable to login to my system using my standard user account it gives me `System Program Problem`
please could somebody help me with this?, if I cannot login I will need to reinstall my system.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
In my home directory I found .compiz and .compiz-1 directories I renamed the first one to compiz-old and the second one to .compiz so ubuntu now uses the second one for unity and this solved the problem.